# Copy to Clipboard and edit the Clipboard

Tags: windows, excel, documentation

Let's say I've copied from Google Excel Sheet this content:

```
Click Here
```

I would like to edit the Clipboard to be something like:

```
<div class="button">Click Here</div>
```

Is there a way that I can do that on Windows?

Comment: What are you trying to achive & in what format? HTML?  Are you trying to create a HTML page that edits clipboard contents?

Comment: I want to copy from the Excel, and when I'm pasting to the HTML editor I want to paste it inside a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your description that all you're really looking for is a good Macro software, there are literally hundreds of possibilities, one of my favourites for Windows is [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/download.php).

**EDIT:**

Quite some time has passed since I posted my original answer, and I have since switched to using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows, and [Espanso](https://espanso.org/) on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

for a simple html text field to paste text to.
use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
        Paste Text Here
    </textarea>

   </body>
 </html>
```